# 'to have answered that call' versus' to answer that call'

Tags: grammar

1. I know now that I would have turned  from my wife's deathbed to **have answered** that call.
2. I know now that I would have turned from my wife's deathbed to **answer** that call.

What is difference between two sentences above?

Comment: The difference is that only sentence no. 2 makes any sense. The conditional 'would have turned to...' requires an infinitive. You are at your wife's deathbed (may it never happen!). The phone rings. You turn to answer it, not 'turn to have answered it'.

Comment: I see sentence no1 on page 149 of ' Leadership in turbulent times' by Doris Kearns Goodwin. I am not sure that is wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's just poor style, or bad editing. I still don't like it.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. What the speaker knows now (and whether he did or didn't answer the call) are syntactically irrelevant elements. If he *had* answered, he'd say *I turned from my wife's deathbed to answer that call.* It's syntactic nonsense to say *I turned from my wife's deathbed to **have answered** that call.* Any cited source for that second construction is just badly written.

Answer (score 4):

Think of that "past infinitive" construction as meaning something like "to be in a state where I (or you, or they, or whatever pronoun applies) have done whatever".

So "To have answered that call" means something like "to be in the state where I have answered that call".

This can make sense after words like "want", "intend" or "expect", but not in many other contexts. It makes no sense for a purpose clause like this one - you would have turned in order to anwer the phone, not in order to be in the position of having answered the phone before.

Comment: very deftly expressed!